# Get /wp-login.php on a non Wordpress site - Hacking attempt?

Tags: node.js

In the console of my node app, I keep seeing requests for GET /wp-login.php

After Googling I discovered it's the standard address for the login page of the WordPress platform which I do not use.

Is it safe to assume that someone is trying to run a malicious script on my site hoping it is based on WordPress?

What actions should I take?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These are likely automated scans searching for low hanging fruit. They can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep including a log file inside your website. This is my script:

```
<?php
 file_put_contents( "logs.txt", $_SERVER[ "REMOTE_ADDR" ]." - ".$_SERVER[ "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" ]." - ".date("Y/m/d [ h:i:sa ]")." - http://".$_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ].$_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ]." - ".$_SERVER[ "HTTP_USER_AGENT" ]."\n".file_get_contents( 'hahahaha.txt' ) );
?>
```